# Linux thread priority

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have question about Linux pthread synchronization and scheduling like code below

```
/*
 * multithread.c
 *
 * Demonstrate use of a multi threading and scheduling using pthreads
 *
 * compile with
 cc multithread.c -o multithread -lrt -lpthread
 *
 */

#include <pthread.h>    /* header file for pthreads */
#include <unistd.h>     /* header file for POSIX conformance */
#include <time.h>       /* header file for POSIX time management */
#include <sched.h>      /* header file for POSIX scheduling */
#include <stdio.h>      /* header file for standard input/outputlibrary */
#define _REENTRANT      /* macro to ensure system calls are reentrant */

void *threadA(void *);   /* predefine threadA routine */
void *threadB(void *);   /* predefine threadB routine */
void *threadC(void *);   /* predefine threadC routine */

pthread_t threadA_id,threadB_id,threadC_id,main_id; /* thread identifiers */
pthread_attr_t attrA,attrB,attrC;  /* thread attribute structures */
struct sched_param param;          /* scheduling structure for thread attributes */

int policy=SCHED_FIFO;
int priority_min,priority_max;     /* for range of priority levels */

/* main routine */
int main()
{
  struct timespec start;
  int status;                        /* check that system calls return ok */

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);        /* get the time   */
  printf("Start time is: %d seconds %d nano_seconds\n",start.tv_sec,start.tv_nsec);

  /* Set processor affinity */ 
  unsigned long mask = 1; /* use only 1 CPU core */
  unsigned int len = sizeof(mask);
  status = sched_setaffinity(0, len, &mask);
  if (status < 0) perror("sched_setaffinity");
  status = sched_getaffinity(0, len, &mask);
  if (status < 0) perror("sched_getaffinity");

  /* Find priority limits */

  priority_max = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
  priority_min = sched_get_priority_min(policy);

  /* Set priority and policy of main thread */

  main_id = pthread_self();
  param.sched_priority=priority_max;
  status = pthread_setschedparam(main_id, policy, &param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam"); /* error check */

  /* Create threadA */

  param.sched_priority = priority_min+1;
  pthread_attr_init(&attrA);
  status = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attrA,policy);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedpolicy"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrA,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedparam"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_create(&threadA_id, &attrA, threadA, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_create"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_setschedparam(threadA_id,policy,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam");

  /* Create threadB */

  param.sched_priority = priority_min+1;
  pthread_attr_init(&attrB);
  status = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attrB,policy);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedpolicy"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrB,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedparam"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_create(&threadB_id, &attrB, threadB, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_create"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_setschedparam(threadB_id,policy,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam");

  /* Create threadC */

  param.sched_priority = priority_min+1;
  pthread_attr_init(&attrC);
  status = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attrC,policy);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedpolicy"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrC,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedparam"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_create(&threadC_id, &attrC, threadC, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_create"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_setschedparam(threadC_id,policy,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam");

  /* Join threads - force main to wait for the thread to terminate */  
  printf("main() waiting for threads\n");

  status = pthread_join(threadA_id, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_join(threadA_id, NULL)"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_join(threadB_id, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_join(threadB_id, NULL)"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_join(threadC_id, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_join(threadC_id, NULL)"); /* error check */

  printf("\nmain() reporting that all threads have terminated\n");
  return(0);

}  /* end of main */

void *threadA(void *arg)
{
  int j;

  for(j=1;j<=10;j++){
    printf("a");
  }
  return (NULL);
}

void *threadB(void *arg)
{
  int j;

  for(j=1;j<=10;j++){
    printf("b");
  }
  return (NULL);
}

void *threadC(void *arg)
{
  int j;

  for(j=1;j<=10;j++){
    printf("c");
  }
  return (NULL);
}
```

My question is why the output of this threads result is like this

[image: output]

why the program doesn't print aaaaa first and than bbbbb and the last ccccc ? Even though I set the thread priority with same priority except the main thread and I set the FIFO mode policy for thread processing.

Does anyone have experience about this case or about linux thread synchronization and scheduling ?

Comment: Thread priority is completely unrelated to the thread synchronization. It's just a hint to a thread scheduler to provide greater or smaller bandwidth to a given thread. Use regular thread synchronization procedures like wait() instead.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the output is cccccbbbbbaaaaa not aaaaabbbbcccc even though the code create thread A first then thread B and C ?

Comment: It doesn't matter when a thread is created. Threads are essentially parallel. Without an explicit synchronization, all threads may run concurrently with any speed each. Occasionally you may even get 'cbaabcbacccaabbba'.

Answer (score 3):

The crux of the issue here is that the SCHED_FIFO policy gets applied as the threads become *runnable*.  From the man page:

```
2) When a blocked SCHED_FIFO thread becomes runnable, it will be
   inserted at the end of the list for its priority.
```

What your example clearly shows is that there is a difference between `pthread_create()` returning and the new thread actually being runnable.  With the main thread being set to the maximum priority and also being FIFO itself, it prevents the new threads from being added to the run queue at all, until the main thread finally blocks on something.  At that point the newly created threads all get initially in an unspecified order, and the `SCHED_FIFO` policy applies thereafter.

To prove that `SCHED_FIFO` does in fact work, consider this modification, which adds a semaphore for each thread, and a delay in the main thread to get everything runnable once:

```
/*
 * multithread.c
 *
 * Demonstrate use of a multi threading and scheduling using pthreads
 *
 * compile with
 cc multithread.c -o multithread -lrt -lpthread
 *
 */
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700
#define _REENTRANT      /* macro to ensure system calls are reentrant */

#include <pthread.h>    /* header file for pthreads */
#include <unistd.h>     /* header file for POSIX conformance */
#include <time.h>       /* header file for POSIX time management */
#include <sched.h>      /* header file for POSIX scheduling */
#include <stdio.h>      /* header file for standard input/outputlibrary */
#include <semaphore.h>

void *threadA(void *);   /* predefine threadA routine */
void *threadB(void *);   /* predefine threadB routine */
void *threadC(void *);   /* predefine threadC routine */

pthread_t threadA_id,threadB_id,threadC_id,main_id; /* thread identifiers */
pthread_attr_t attrA,attrB,attrC;  /* thread attribute structures */
struct sched_param param;          /* scheduling structure for thread attributes */

int policy=SCHED_FIFO;
int priority_min,priority_max;     /* for range of priority levels */

sem_t sem1;
sem_t sem2;
sem_t sem3;

/* main routine */
int main()
{
  struct timespec start;
  int status;                        /* check that system calls return ok */

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);        /* get the time   */
  printf("Start time is: %d seconds %d nano_seconds\n",start.tv_sec,start.tv_nsec);

  sem_init(&sem1, 0, 0);
  sem_init(&sem2, 0, 0);
  sem_init(&sem3, 0, 0);

  /* Set processor affinity */ 
  cpu_set_t mask;
  CPU_SET(1, &mask);  /* use only 1 CPU core */
  unsigned int len = sizeof(mask);
  status = sched_setaffinity(0, len, &mask);
  if (status < 0) perror("sched_setaffinity");
  status = sched_getaffinity(0, len, &mask);
  if (status < 0) perror("sched_getaffinity");

  /* Find priority limits */

  priority_max = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
  priority_min = sched_get_priority_min(policy);

  /* Set priority and policy of main thread */

  main_id = pthread_self();
  param.sched_priority=priority_max;
  status = pthread_setschedparam(main_id, policy, &param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam"); /* error check */

  /* Create threadA */

  param.sched_priority = priority_min+1;
  pthread_attr_init(&attrA);
  status = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attrA,policy);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedpolicy"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrA,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedparam"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_create(&threadA_id, &attrA, threadA, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_create"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_setschedparam(threadA_id,policy,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam");

  /* Create threadB */

  param.sched_priority = priority_min+1;
  pthread_attr_init(&attrB);
  status = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attrB,policy);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedpolicy"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrB,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedparam"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_create(&threadB_id, &attrB, threadB, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_create"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_setschedparam(threadB_id,policy,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam");

  /* Create threadC */

  param.sched_priority = priority_min+1;
  pthread_attr_init(&attrC);
  status = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attrC,policy);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedpolicy"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrC,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedparam"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_create(&threadC_id, &attrC, threadC, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_create"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_setschedparam(threadC_id,policy,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam");

  /* Join threads - force main to wait for the thread to terminate */  
  printf("main() waiting for threads\n");

  /* delay so all threads become blocked on semaphore */
  {
    struct timespec ts;
    ts.tv_sec = 0;
    ts.tv_nsec = 25000000;
    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, &ts, NULL);
  }

  /* post sems so threads become runnable in desired order */
  sem_post(&sem1);
  sem_post(&sem2);
  sem_post(&sem3);

  status = pthread_join(threadA_id, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_join(threadA_id, NULL)"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_join(threadB_id, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_join(threadB_id, NULL)"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_join(threadC_id, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_join(threadC_id, NULL)"); /* error check */

  printf("\nmain() reporting that all threads have terminated\n");
  return(0);

}  /* end of main */

void *threadA(void *arg)
{
  int j;

  printf("x");

  sem_wait(&sem1);

  for(j=1;j<=10;j++){
    printf("a");
  }
  return (NULL);
}

void *threadB(void *arg)
{
  int j;

  printf("y");

  sem_wait(&sem2);

  for(j=1;j<=10;j++){
    printf("b");
  }
  return (NULL);
}

void *threadC(void *arg)
{
  int j;

  printf("z");

  sem_wait(&sem3);

  for(j=1;j<=10;j++){
    printf("c");
  }
  return (NULL);
}
```

This delay allows all three threads to get initially scheduled once, and then they each become blocked on their respective semaphore.  Then the main task (still highest priority) posts all three semaphores so all three threads become runnable, however we have controlled the order with which they become runnable.  The output of this on my machine shows:

```
Start time is: 1520004544 seconds 516899746 nano_seconds
main() waiting for threads
zyxaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc
main() reporting that all threads have terminated
```

Comment: I'm still not understand, why the program still run in the opposite order  (threadC->threadB->threadA) before using semaphore and why after implement semaphore the threads can run in correct order ? Could you give me more explanation ? Thx

Comment: Because the FIFO scheduling algorithm applies as threads transition from the _blocked_ state to the _runnable_ state.  New threads are not starting in the "blocked" state; they previously didn't exist.  When you create new threads, you do not have direct control over exactly when they become _runnable_ threads.  However, by allowing the threads to become blocked on a semaphore, we can exercise this specific state transition.  Posting the sem will transition the thread from _blocked_ to _runnable_ state and threads will be put into the run queue in the order they became runnable.